# How to ignore a specific transitive dependency from all dependencies in Gradle

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, transitive-dependency

How can I ignore a specific transitive dependency in Gradle?

For example, many libraries (such as Spring and ...) depend on `commons-logging`, I want to replace `commons-logging` with `SLF4J` (and its jcl-over-slf4j bridge).

Is it any way in my gradle script to mention it once, and not for each dependency which depends on `commons-logging`?

I was thinking of an script, iterating on all dependencies and adding some `exclude` on all of them, is there any better solution? And how that script be like?

Comment: Please try resolution strategy : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23124509/how-to-exclude-specific-jars-from-web-inf-lib/30393301#30393301

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'commons-logging'
}
```

Comment: Or: `configurations.all { exclude group: 'commons-logging' }`.

Comment: Is there any way to exclude a specific version of a group?

Answer (score 18):

Came here with the same problem but ended up using the following to do an actual replace. Posting it for completeness' sake.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
        if(it.requested.name == 'commons-logging') {
            it.useTarget 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.7'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kudos for your answer and the elegance of Gradle when dealing with such tasks.

Comment: I'd like to add that in the meantime a new Gradle version is out and it has module replacements. Haven't tried it yet, but it looks as if they might do the same thing.

Comment: Came for the question, found the better answer. ;)