# How to exclude specific jars from WEB-INF/lib

Tags: gradle

I have the following gradle projects:

```
jar-module-A
  +-- JavaEE lib(Dependency)

war-module-A
  +-- jar-module-A
```

I want to exclude JavaEE lib from WEB-INF/lib.

1. Using providedCompile:

   Since jar-module-A is not a web module but jar, I cannot use providedCompile in build.gradle of jar-module-A.
2. configurations { runtime.exclude JavaEE-lib }

   It excludes JavaEE from not only runtime but also testRuntime, It fails my unit tests in war-module-A by ClassNotFoundException.

How can mitigate this situation?

Comment: Isn't `providedRuntime` what You're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. providedRuntime is a method of war plugin as well as providedCompile. So I cannot use it in jar project...

Comment: Ah.. Sure. So can You provide a sample gradle build file that illustrates the problem and allow others to have a try?

Comment: Sure. I have placed a sample at https://github.com/ruimo/gradle-sample.

Comment: In module_a, execute gradle uploadArchives. then in module_b, execute gradle test assemble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Brute force* solution would be:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven {
    url "file:///tmp/repo"
  }
}

uploadArchives {
  repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
      repository(url: "file:///tmp/repo")
    }   
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile group: 'ruimo', name: 'module_a', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
  testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
}

war {
    classpath = classpath.filter {
        it.name != 'javaee-api-6.0.jar'
    }   
}
```

for `module_b`. It might be filename dependent (not sure of that). Maybe will have a look later on, but not sure - short with time.

**UPDATE**

More sophisticated:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven {
    url "file:///tmp/repo"
  }
}

uploadArchives {
  repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
      repository(url: "file:///tmp/repo")
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile(group: 'ruimo', name: 'module_a', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT') {
    transitive = false// here You can exclude particular dependency, not necessarily all
  }
  providedCompile group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '6.0'
  testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
}
```

No I see it can be done with many ways. It depends on what are other requirements regard build.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Brute force solution is fine for me. Additional note: In my environment, wired ClassFormatError occurs (1.7.0_45-b18 + Gradle 1.9) while testing but it seems another issue.

Comment: Well.. it's not so brute ;]

Comment: ClassFormatError was caused by creating Cookie instance in unit test sample and it is not gradle issue.

Comment: Ah yes.. I also had this error but thought it was on purpose.

Comment: Sure! it seems quite comprehensive solution for me.

Comment: @ruimo if it works for you remember to accept the answer! (tick icon)

Comment: Thanks for advice. I clicked the check icon.

Answer (score 0):

If the **transitive** is not working, can try **resolution startegy**.
I was fed up with the transitive or even normal exclude.

https://docs.gradle.org/2.2.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html

```
dependencies{
        compile(group: 'ruimo', name: 'module_a', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT')
    }

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force ruimo:module_a:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    }
}
```