# exclude specific version of jar or module file?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

/*

 * there is duplicate rocon_app_manager_msgs: v0.6.9 and 0.7.8

 * common_tools must have v0.7.8

 * robot_remocon must have 0.6.9.

 * so here is a solution, that robot_remocon compile:

 * exclude rocon_app_manager_msgs v0.7.8 only for this project.

*/

```
compile 'org.ros.rosjava_messages:rocon_app_manager_msgs:[0.6,0.7)'
compile  project(':common_tools')
```

i want to exclude specific version of rocon_app_manager_msgs, 0.7.8v and above.

i try something like this:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'org.ros.rosjava_messages', module: 'rocon_app_manager_msgs:0.7+'
}
```

and other similar options, but it doesn't work.

can you help me?

Comment: Could you explain more your case? Why if version doesn't match you don't want to exclude?

Comment: I don't see a way to do what you want. The API docs for the Gradle exclude rule are at https://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ExcludeRule.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it without configuration:
I just use transtive = false to specific project:

```
compile  (project(':common_tools')) {
            transitive = false
}
```

I hope it will help for other.

Tal.

Answer (score 0):

Try '**resolution strategy**'

Please go through my answer in :
[How to exclude specific jars from WEB-INF/lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23124509/how-to-exclude-specific-jars-from-web-inf-lib/30393301#30393301)

Comment: already solve the problem. i will use your strategy next time :)